# MySQL: Trying to populate data into one column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

Table A has several columns, including `FirstName` and `LastName`
Table B has different columns, including `FirstName`, `LastName` and `EmployeeID`

I added `EmployeeID` into Table A. I now want to populate Table A's `Employee ID`'s from Table B's `Employee ID`'s, using the first and last name (we currently have no one working with the same name - the design of this table was weird like that)

I've attempted a few things, but I keep coming back to

```
INSERT INTO TableA (EMPLOYEE_ID) A
SELECT B.EMPLOYEE_ID FROM TableB B
WHERE A.First_name = B.First_name
AND A.Last_name = B.Last_name
```

But I keep getting a syntax error - MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near A. I don't know how to use this syntax when dealing with `Insert` statements, I think, or if this is the right way at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like you already have data in TableA that you want to update.  If that is the case, you need to use an `UPDATE` statement.  Here's an example:

```
UPDATE TableA A
SET EMPLOYEE_ID =
  (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
   FROM TableB B
   WHERE B.First_name = A.First_name
   AND B.Last_name = A.Last_name)
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
   FROM TableB B
   WHERE B.First_name = A.First_name
   AND B.Last_name = A.Last_name)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I'm very rusty on my SQL skills, so I forgot about Update completely

Comment: I get an error like this: _Subquery returns more than 1 row_. Any suggestions on it.

Comment: Its awesome how exists is used here to update multiple records.

Answer (score 1):

Question: Are first and last name guaranteed to be unique?

Also, this needs to be an update.

```
UPDATE TableA A
SET a.employee_id = (SELECT employee_id FROM TableB WHERE first_name = a.first_name AND last_name = a.last_name)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE first_name = a.first_name AND last_name = a.last_name)
```

Comment: They are. At this point the company only has 20 people, so I needed to get on this before we start growing more. I don't know why anybody thought it was a good idea to not include a key to employee names

Comment: Why do we have to parts in update? The first part is straith forward (Select ..) and the second part is WHERE EXISTS (Select)? Is it only possible to use WHERE EXISTS? That means: UPDATE TAbleA A SET a.employee_id WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...).